# When using "Rehearse Timings" in Powerpoint, is there a way to back up without having the timer reset?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I often use "Rehearse Timings" within Powerpoint to gauge how long a given talk will be and where I'm spending my time.  When giving talks (whether practicing or for real), I often back up in my slides to emphasize a point, and am finding that this causes Powerpoint to subtract those slides' times from the running time and the per-slide timings.  Is there a way to change/override this behavior so that it continues to time monotonically?

For example, say that in my practice talk, I:

- spend 2 minutes on slide 1
- advance to slide 2 and talk for 30 seconds on it
- back up to quickly relate something I've said back to slide 1 for 5 seconds
- advance past slide 2 to slide 3

Rather than showing the elapsed time as ~2:36 (the total time spent on the talk so far), when I back up, Powerpoint erases the 2 minutes spent on slide 1 and the 30 seconds spent on slide 2, such that when I get to slide 3, the running timer says "0:06" with 0:05 spent on slide 1 and 0:01 on slide 2.

I believe that the reason it does this is for people who are rehearsing timings in order to have the slideshow automatically advance after showing each slide for a set amount of time.  But for those of us who are using it to rehearse and get a sense for how long our talk will take, it ends up giving an incorrect and too-short result.

I'm wondering whether there's any way to configure it to just accumulate times rather than subtracting when backing up so that I'd see that I spent 2:05 on slide 1 and 0:31 on slide 2 for a total of 2:36.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse a slide again in a Slide Slow, the proper way to do that is by configuring a ***Custom Slide Show*** (which allows you to reuse/replay a slide in any place you want).

Click ***Custom Slide Show*** (in the *Slow Show* tab) and create a new custom show. To start, add all slides to the custom show, and then add again the slides you want to reuse/revisit and move it up to the correct position.

Then go to **Set Up Slide Show** (in the same group as *Rehearse Timing*) and select your custom show under ***Show slides***.

And that way, when you do the ***Rehearse Timings*** it will bring you up Slide 1 again after Slide 2, and correctly time the progress.

---

If you don't know beforehand what slide exactly you'll be going back on, then I don't believe this feature is for you. The main point of this Rehearse Timings is to then be able to set the Slideshow to run automatically based on those timings.

To simply time how long the whole Slide Shows will take, you can use a Stopwatch...

Comment: The problem with that approach for me is that I don't always know when I'm going to want to go back and touch on a previous slide again or not, particularly when rehearsing.  If I can anticipate that I'm going to definitely return to a slide, I typically just make a second copy of it in sequential order.  It's the off-the-cuff "like we saw here" rewinds that are biting me when trying to use the feature.

Comment: I'd say that this feature isn't meant for your need then, just use a stopwatch... The whole point of this rehearsing feature and keeping this timer is to them be able to apply it for the automatic slideshow (which isn't the way you will do when you play your slideshow.)

Comment: That's the unfortunate conclusion I was coming to before posting this as a last-ditch effort.  The reason just using a stopwatch isn't as nice is that I don't get the per-slide breakdown of where I spent my time, which is valuable.  At least, not without noting it manually after each slide (but that interrupts the flow of the practice).  If I were to phrase this as a feature request for the PPT team, I'd say that there should be a "rehearse timings is monotonic" checkbox that would toggle between the current behavior and an "accumulate only" option.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I missed this comment earlier:  "The main point of this Rehearse Timings is to then be able to set the Slideshow to run automatically based on those timings."  If that's the case, I think it should be renamed from "Rehearse timings" to something like "Capture timings" or the like.  (I realize you may not work for Microsoft, but maybe someone reading this does).